Subscription pipe logic errantly processing when using switchMap on button press
Edit: I have found a workaround by using updating my event filter to:
filter(event => 
    event.type === EventType.NavigationEnd && 
    this.route.snapshot.queryParams['test'])

which solves getting the params for my issue, however the question remains about the errant behavior of switchMap inside pipe(), so the issue remains open.

I have the following subscription to Angular's routing events in a service:
constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
) {
    this.router.events.pipe(
        // Filter events to NavigationEnd only
        filter(event => {
            console.log(event);
            return event instanceof NavigationEnd;
        }),

        // Get all query params
        switchMap(() => this.route.queryParams)
    ).subscribe(params => {
        console.log("ENTERED");
        console.log(params);
    });
}

The service is pulled into my main app component via the constructor to allow this to trigger anywhere in my app:
public constructor(
    private testService: TestService
) { }

I expect it to filter all router events that don't match NavigationEnd and only log params when the NavigationEnd event is detected.
When navigating to the url via my browser address bar, I successfully see that the only router events I see my logs under is the NavigationEnd event:

Moving to implementation, I created a button that will add a query parameter when clicked to the URL:
<button (click)="addTestToRoute()">Click me to add test to route</button>

Which has the following component method:
public addTestToRoute(): void {
    let newParams = { test: "12345" };

    this.router.navigate(
        [],
        {
            queryParams: newParams,
            queryParamsHandling: 'merge'
        });
}

When clicking this button, the values are errantly logged under GuardsCheckEnd, but also logged under NavigationEnd.  I am confused as to why this is, as any logic I apply to try and control the flow of the pipe logic is not adhered to and the log is ALWAYS displayed under GuardsCheckEnd.  To note, I have no routing guards in place:

Any help towards understanding why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

That is unexpected, but can you try to use EventType instead? event.type === EventType.NavigationEnd

@OscarLudick updating the filter event block to return event.type === EventType.NavigationEnd; produces the same outcome.

@OscarLudick The more I've played with this, the more I think it's due to the switchMap. From what I understand about switchMap it cancels the previous subscription so it would lose context on previous filters, and I can remove the switchMap and console log the event inside the subscription just fine, both entering the url and using the button click event show only the NavigationEnd event. I can solve getting query params by using this.route.snapshot.queryParams inside the subscription block and checking for my value there, but I'm going to leave the question open as it still puzzles me.

It happens because you switched stream to this.route.queryParams observable.
Here is the general idea:

During the first navigation cycle events are filtered up until NavigationEnd event. switchMap switches stream to this.route.queryParams as a source.
New navigation cycle starts after button click, in a meantime ActivatedRoute emits route params as well.
Subscription receives emitted value --> this is the point where your first ENTERED message appears around GuardsCheckEnd
NavigationEnd is fired and invalidates previous subscription. --> second ENTERED

Not sure about the details, but most likely, queryParams emits new param values at the end or right after GuardsCheckEnd.

I would think if the cycle was running twice, then twice the amount of navigation events would be logged. Once NavigationEnd is reached the cycle ends, I have no evidence that theres another loop occurring.

There are no 2 cycles here, there are 2 different streams - one from this.router.events and one from this.route.queryParams. The result you've got happens due to queryParams emits first value before NavigationEnd happens and then it emits the same value for the second time due to re-subscription in switchMap after NavigationEnd event passes the filters

Here is example code of similar behavior: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-playground-test-n9zsi1?file=index.ts

Wouldn't the filter inside of the pipe prevent any further processing as it doesn't detect the filter event EndNavigation occurring? Why would a switchMap fire off an emission when (to the best of my understanding) it wouldn't even be considered due to the filter logic?

I've updated your stackblitz and it's as I assumed, the filter controls how the pipe runs, theres no emission from the switchMap if the filter conditional isn't met.  You can see "second" is never emitted because the value "first" is filtered out, but "second 2" IS displayed because we find the value the filter is looking for with "first 2":
https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-playground-test-op86f7?file=index.ts

Here is a better example with filter - https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-playground-test-pexbz3?file=index.ts. And no, filter does not affect stream within switchMap anyhow. switchMap (and any other ...Map operators) essentially channels outer stream into inner stream. See marble example.

So if the filter never matches any values, no values from within the switchMap are emitted: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-playground-test-kdngcg?file=index.ts
The only time we ever see values from the switchMap are when theres a matching filter, and it will immediately emit the first value from the switchMap and all future values if any are set: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-playground-test-orui3v?file=index.ts
It stands that if there is no matching filter value, then the switchMap is never accessed, which in my original example shows that it is indeed being accessed before a match

You are right about everything but the original example. In your original example, you put service in root component which means that your subscription will be created immediately. It will catch initial navigation including NavigationEnd - this leads to switchMap subscription. Your code can be fixed by replacing switchMap with currentNavigation: map(() => this.router.currentNavigation.finalUrl.queryParams).
